# Function Overloading in Derived Class

Tags: c++, inheritance

I want to know the below code is correct or not

```
class A
{
public :
    int show (int x, int y);
};

class B : public A
{
public : 
    float show (int a, int b); // can i overload this function ?
};
```

the show function is present in both base and derived class with different written types.
I know function overloading concept (can not overload with different return types).

Is this possible to do so?

Comment: class & public: should all be lower case

Comment: Don't forgot to accept answer witch helps you ...

Comment: Overloading won't work, what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

The code will be compiled successfully. The method `A::show` will not be overloaded but hidden.

You can call this method with the scope operator.

Comment: thanks for `scope resolution operator`.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027724/c-function-overriding) or this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0y01k918%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

```
Class A
{
Public :
virtual int show (int x, inty) = 0;
};

class B:Public A
{
Public : 
float show (int x, int y);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

When i declare base obj and point it to derived class :

A aObj;
B bObj;
aObju = &bObj;

bObj.Show(); // Which function will be called base class or derived class?

Answer (score 0):

If you create a derived class object like

1)

```
B b; 
b.show();
```

OR

2)

```
A* b = new B();
b->show();
```

Will always look into derived class, and call B::show().

This is for your particular example, where no virtual functions are present, if virtual functions are present in the base class, the second case can give different results in other cases, but in this particular example even base class virtual functions will make no difference.